# What does HSJOIN mean in an Explain Plan?

Tags: explain, db2

I have the following `EXPLAIN PLAN` results from a query on my DB2 database.

```
0 SELECT STATEMENT ( Estimated Costs =  5.928E+02 [timerons] )
       1 RETURN
           2 HSJOIN
               3 [O] FETCH LTBP
                   4 IXSCAN LTBP~M #key columns:  0
               5 [I] FETCH LTBK
                   6 IXSCAN LTBK~V #key columns:  0
```

What does the `HSJOIN` on line 2 mean?

Comment: what type of database server?

Comment: @David: oops, DB2.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [hash join](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0021327.htm)